# Entity Framework 5: Table-per-Type mapping with concrete base class

Tags: .net, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, table-per-type

I'm working on an EF5 Code First application, and things have been going well so far, but I've hit a bump, and I'm hoping someone can suggest a solution.

Basically, I've got a base class, and a few derived classes, and I'm wondering how to handle their mapping.  Here's a ridiculously simplified example:

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("EmployeePerson")]
public class EmployeePerson : Person
{
  public int HoursWorked { get; set; }
}

[Table("CustomerPerson")]
public class CustomerPerson : Person
{
  public int DollarsSpent { get; set; }
}
```

So far, this is a typical Table-per-Type scenario, except for the hitch that the base class is *not* abstract -- it's possible to have a `Person` who is not an `EmployeePerson` or a `CustomerPerson`.  I'm having some trouble getting the EF to accept that, and when I try to load such an entity by ID, the ugly query generated by the EF returns no rows.

Has anyone implemented anything like this before?  Does TPT-style mapping always require the base class to be abstract?  I haven't been able to find any examples to the contrary, but no real confirmation either.  I can think of a few ugly workarounds I might be able to use if I have to, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution if there is one.

(One further hitch: I'm working against a third-party database, and so I can't make any changes to the schema.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your "ugly" solution is to introduce an abstract base class `PersonBase` (or similar) and make `Person` an empty derived class, my comment would be: do it! It isnot ugly at all, because it leaves room to changing `Person` later without affecting the other derived classes. Currently, that would be much harder. You'd have to introduce the abstract class later, which is a more drastic change in existing code.

About your issue: I can't repro that with EF 5 (VS 2012 .Net 4.5). Maybe there are more things going on in your real model.

Comment: You're right, the simplified tests I ran apparently weren't simplified enough -- a totally trivial example works the way I hoped.  Now to find out what I'm doing elsewhere to cause this...thanks for your help!